# compare two text file and save the output match

Tags: python, file, file-io

I have two text files and I want to compare them and save the matched columns to a new text 
file.

**file1:**

```
114.74721

114.85107

2.96667

306.61756
```

**file2:**

```
115.06603 0.00294 5.90000

114.74721 0.00674 5.40000

114.85107 0.00453 6.20000

111.17744 0.00421 5.50000

192.77787 0.03080 3.20000

189.70226 0.01120 5.00000

0.46762 0.00883 3.70000

2.21539 0.01290 3.50000

2.96667 0.01000 3.60000

5.43310 0.00393 5.50000

0.28537 0.00497 5.10000

308.82348 0.00183 6.60000

306.61756 0.00359 5.20000
```

And I want the output to be:

```
114.74721 0.00674 5.40000

114.85107 0.00453 6.20000

2.96667 0.01000 3.60000

306.61756 0.00359 5.20000
```

I used a script but there is something wrong because the output file more rows than the file1 which it should be the same.Could you help me?

```
file1=open("file1.txt","r")
file2=open("file2.txt","r")
file3=open("output.txt","w")
  for line1 in file1.readlines():
    file2.seek(0)
    for line2 in file2.readlines():
      if line1.strip() in line2:
        file3.writerow(line2)
```

**Edit**

***From file1.txt***

114.74721

114.85107

2.96667

306.61756

152.70581

150.04497

91.41869

91.41869

91.73398

92.35076

117.68963

117.69291

115.97827

168.14476

169.94404

73.00571

156.02833

156.02833

***From file3.txt***

114.74721 0.00674 5.40000

114.85107 0.00453 6.20000

2.96667 0.01000 3.60000

306.61756 0.00359 5.20000

152.70581 0.02780 2.70000

150.04497 0.00211 6.00000

91.41869 0.00500 3.70000

91.73398 0.00393 4.30000

92.35076 0.00176 5.80000

117.68963 0.15500 2.20000

117.69291 0.15100 2.50000

115.97827 0.00722 7.80000

168.14476 0.00383 5.50000

169.94404 0.00539 4.80000

73.00571 0.00876 3.80000

156.02833 0.00284 6.30000

156.64645 0.01290 3.50000

156.65070 0.02110 4.40000

If you see the line 7 and line 8 have the same value 91.41869 in file1.txt but in file3.txt it only mention line 7 but not 8. The same also in lines 17 and 18.

Answer (score 0):

```
FILE1 = "file1.txt"
FILE2 = "file2.txt"
OUTPUT = "file3.txt"

with open(FILE1) as inf:
    match = set(line.strip() for line in inf)

with open(FILE2) as inf, open(OUTPUT, "w") as outf:
    for line in inf:
        if line.split(' ', 1)[0] in match:
            outf.write(line)
```

or, if they HAVE to be in the same order,

```
with open(FILE1) as inf:
    items = [line.strip() for line in inf]
    match = {val:i for i,val in enumerate(items)}
    outp  = ['\n'] * len(items)

with open(FILE2) as inf, open(OUTPUT, "w") as outf:
    for line in inf:
        val = line.split(' ', 1)[0]
        try:
            outp[match[val]] = line
        except KeyError:
            pass
    outf.write(''.join(outp))
```

Note that the first version will write out as many matches as it finds - if two lines in FILE2 start with "114.74721" you will get both of them - while the second will only keep the last match found.

Comment: The first code give me output file which is less than file1 and the second code give me an output file as the same number of rows as file but have many Blank rows.

Comment: Are the search values in FILE1 and FILE2 are identical? I am doing string comparison, so "114.74721" != "114.747210". Blank lines in the second-case output file correspond to values from FILE1 not found in FILE2.

Comment: Yes, they are identical. The first line value in file1 comes after so many blank lines in the output file. So blank lines does not correspond to values from file1 not found in file2. The missing values are those of the repeated values in file1 it only write out one value of the repeated value in the output file.

Comment: what I should do next?

Comment: Can you post a few of the lines from FILE2 which should have matched but didn't, and the corresponding lines from FILE1?